# Client sent unsolicited image via iMessage. In disgust, I deleted it. Can I get it back?

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages, restore, messages-in-icloud

So many paid applications are nearly guaranteeing results and the information I'm finding here is way out of date (2015, 2014, etc.).

My Messages are backed up to iCloud. I don't want to erase my phone because I have a lot of 2FA accounts on it and it would be a nightmare to restore it. Plus, it's been about five days since iCloud. Maybe the backup is erased.

I have a Mac, iPhone, and iPad. The Mac was on at the time so it would have received the image. I deleted the image on the iPad.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried going to Photos and looking in the Recently Deleted album?  I believe images are kept there for 30 days after they're deleted.

Comment: Not on the iPad, no, but on the iPhone. I’ll try that.

Comment: The iPad is where I deleted them.

Comment: The device doesn't matter if you deleted them from iCloud (as long as the device was signed-in with the same Apple ID).  You can also go to iCloud.com and [recover them there](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/delete-and-recover-photos-and-videos-mm08b49040b5/icloud).

Comment: Well, it’s not there. I suppose deleting an image directly from messages is a different route. A shame but the people I reported this to don’t seem to want the proof. Thanks for your ideas.